# Select first 100 characters of a text field by default

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Is it possible to select the first 100 characters of a database table's text field by default for all my find() calls? I know how to do it by a custom finder or by a virtual field, but none of these are fulfil my requirements. I would need the full text rearly.

Comment: do you mean to take first 100 characters from an object property which has text attribute?

Comment: @marmeladze no, database table field

Comment: if you use mysql, try substring function. `substring(field, 0, 100)`. 

if you want to stay in bounds of framwrok, you can also define a static function that gets first 100 characters from a string, and pass your field's object to it. php's built-in substr should help you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: @marmeladze I now how to do it on mysql, but I would need some cakephp specific solution.

Comment: as i said above, define a static function in your model class. use php's built-in `substr`, which takes a string and returns first 100 chars. then import and use it elsewhere (in your controller, or in your view).

Comment: Add the field in [**`Model.beforeFind`**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforefind)? You may want to add a little more detail/context to your question.